# calculating average of two column in another column

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the average of columns in another column but getting errror

converted all the nastring na.strings = c("N") to NA but after the class of columns is character.

after this i have NA in place of N in data frame but still the class of column is character

```
df <- data.frame("T_1_1"= c(68,24,"N",105,58,"N",135,126,24),
                 "T_1_2"=c(26,105,"N",73,39,97,46,108,"N"),
                 "T_1_3"=c(93,32,73,103,149,"N",147,113,139),
                 "S_2_1"=c(69,67,94,"N",77,136,137,92,73),
                 "S_2_2"=c(87,67,47,120,85,122,"N",96,79),
                 "S_2_3"= c(150,"N",132,121,29,78,109,40,"N"),
                 "TS1_av"=c(68.5,45.5,94,105,67.5,136,136,109,48.5),
                 "TS2_av"=c(56.5,86,47,96.5,62,109.5,46,102,79),
                 "TS3_av"=c(121.5,32,102.5,112,89,78,128,76.5,139)

)

df$TS1_av <- rowMeans(df[,c(as.numeric(as.character("T_1_1","S_2_1")))], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `readr::parse_number` to extract numbers and replace any string that can't be converted to numeric by `NA`.
the `na` argument allows to specify strings to be interpreted as `NA` (here 'N'). If you don't supply this argument, you get a warning for every string which couldn't be interpreted but it's also replaced by `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df <- df %>% mutate(across(where(is.character),readr::parse_number,na='N'))   
df$TS1_av <- rowMeans(df[,c("T_1_1","S_2_1")], na.rm=TRUE)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
#Change 'N' to NA
df[df == 'N'] <- NA
#Change the type of columns
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
#Take mean of selected columns and add a new column
df$TS1_av <- rowMeans(df[,c("T_1_1","S_2_1")], na.rm=TRUE)
df
```

Comment: this converting the column to as.factor

Comment: You might have other non-numeric columns in your data. In the meantime use`as.is = TRUE` in `type.convert`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

2 Base R solutions:

```
# Columns to subset out: cols => character vector
cols <- c("T_1_1", "S_2_1")

# Option 1: calculate the mean row-wise: TS1_av => numeric vector
df$TS1_av <- apply(df[,cols], 1, function(x){
  mean(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x)), na.rm = TRUE)
  }
)

# Columns to subset out: cols => character vector
cols <- c("T_1_1", "S_2_1")

# Option 2: Coerce to numeric and calculate the row mean:
# TS1_av => numeric vector
df$TS1_av <- rowMeans(
  suppressWarnings(
    vapply(df[,cols], as.numeric, numeric(nrow(df)))
  ),
  na.rm = TRUE
)
```